# what is a fast membership algorithm for a static, large, out-of-core dictionary

Tags: hash, dictionary, static, tree

I have a static dictionary containing millions of keys which refer to values in a sparse data structure stored out-of-core. The number of keys is a small fraction, say 10%, of the number of values. The key size is typically 64-bit. The keys are linearly ordered and the queries will often consist of keys which are close together in this order. Data compression is a factor, but it is the values which are expected to be the biggest contributor to data size rather than the keys. Key compression helps, but is not critical. Query time should be constant, if possible, and fast since a user is interacting with the data.

Given these conditions I would like to know an effective way to query the dictionary to determine whether a specific key is contained in it. Query speed is the top priority, construction time is not as critical.

Currently I'm looking at cache-oblivious b+-trees and order-preserving minimal perfect hashes tied to external storage.

At this point CHD or some other form of hashing seems like a candidate. Since the keys are queried in approximate linear order it seems that an order-preserving hash would avoid cache misses, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to say whether CHD can preserve the order of the keys. Constant-time queries are also desirable. The search is O(1), but the upper limit on query times over the key space is also unknown.

Trees seem less attractive. Although there are some cache-oblivious and cache-specific approaches I think much of the effort is aimed at range queries on dynamic dictionaries rather than constant-time membership queries. Processors and memories, in general, don't like branches.

There have been a number of questions asked along these lines, but this case (hopefully) constrains the problem in a manner that might be useful to others.

any feedback would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: I suggest you to experiment with http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/ and bloom filter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter `Bloom filter is a probabilistic data structure: it tells us that the element either definitely is not in the set or may be in the set`

Comment: thanks Ilya - that looks like a good approach to get started on a prototype.

Comment: i'm just digging into whether CHD can be order-preserving: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-sparsehash

Comment: seems the sparsehash group isn't very active lately, but from what i can gather on the www it's well-regarded and has a CHD implementation. Ilya - please feel free to submit an answer.

Comment: Just to give back.. this might be worth a look, too, if memory/speed tradeoff is attractive: http://giovanni.bajo.it/post/47119962313/golomb-coded-sets-smaller-than-bloom-filters

Comment: Cool link, I'll investigate it, thank you